# fprintf not writing on ^C but is writing on exit

Tags: c, shell, printf, fopen, io-redirection

I am writing a terminal shell language in C called tsh (tech shell). The shell has to be able to handle output redirection (">"). I am using fprintf with fopen to accomplish this.
The issue looks similar to the following:

If I use the redirection as it in my shell with the exit command:

```
tsh$ pwd > out.txt
tsh$ exit

bash$ cat out.txt
/tmp
bash$
```

But if I do the same thing with ctrl+c instead of `exit`:

```
tsh$ pwd > out.txt
tsh$ ^C

bash$ cat out.txt
bash$
```

Which means that the file gets opened but when I stop the process the output of tsh's pwd doesn't get written for some reason.

`tsh$ pwd` does, however, print to stdout just fine if there is no redirection.

The reason I cat the file in bash is because tsh doesn't support non-built-in commands (yet), but considering that the content doesn't get written until I exit my shell, I don't think it would work even if I could cat from my shell.

Also, if the `out.txt` does not exist yet, it **does** get created in both cases, but still only gets written to in the first.
In short, I have no issues obtaining a reference to the file, just writing to it.

This is the current source for tsh.c, compiled with gcc:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

const char EXIT[4] = "exit";
const char PWD[3] = "pwd";
const char * DELIM = " \n\r\t";

FILE * outfile, * infile;

char cwd[1024]; //directory to print at beginning of each line

char in[1024]; //user input
char * token;

int main()
{

    while(1)
    {

        outfile = stdout;   
        infile = stdin;

        getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
        printf("%s$ ",cwd); //prompt with cwd       

        fgets(in, sizeof(in), stdin);

        char * fileref;
        if((fileref = strstr(in,">")))
        {

            fileref = strtok(++fileref, DELIM);
            outfile = fopen(fileref, "w");

        }

        token = strtok(in, DELIM);
        if (token != NULL)
        {
            if(!strncmp(token, EXIT, sizeof(EXIT)))
            {

                token = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
                if (token == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Exiting with status code 0.\n");
                    exit(0);
                }
                else if (isdigit(*token))
                {
                    int code = *token - '0';
                    printf("Exiting with status code %d\n",code);
                    exit(code);
                }
            }
            else if(!strncmp(token, PWD, sizeof(PWD)))
            {
                fprintf(outfile, "%s\n",cwd); //This should get written to the file if I provide a redirection
                continue;
            }

            fputs("\n", outfile);

        }

        fclose(outfile);

    }

}
```

Is there some kind of built-in rollback mechanism that is preventing file writing if the process doesn't exit cleanly? Do I have to intercept and override the ctrl+c signal?

*I am aware that there are many problems and bad practices here*, as this is my first experience with C, but I would appreciate it if suggestions could be limited to the specific problem I am experiencing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably exit() close all open files and flushes their streams, but ^C aborts without streams flushes. You may want catch the ^C and flush files before to stop shell execution. Video output should be unbuffered while files are buffered, this should the reason for which there is no problem without redirection.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/

Comment: Try calling fflush after fprintf.

Comment: Do I close and fflush?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but you can find libreadline helpful for your project: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Comment: I'm not familiar with this shell language of yours, but I guess you could use ^D to to send end-of-file to the input (EOF).

Comment: You also should treat the reading of EOF character on your program and gracefully exit after reading it.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `exit()`, you are causing your process to terminate *in a clean way*, which among other things makes sure any open files are correctly closed (thus any buffered output is flushed).

On the other hand, when you press CTRL+C you are sending a SIGINT to your process, and the default behavior of a process when receiving such signal is to terminate; but this is not a clean process termination (it's similar to what happens when you get a segmentation fault), so any open files are not correctly closed, and if there is any buffered output it will be lost.

In your application, you will be able to resolve the issue you described by fixing a logical error in the code: inside the main `while()` loop, you are calling `fopen()` when you encounter the '>' character in the user input, but when you execute the 'pwd' command you don't close the file stream returned by `fopen()`, and at the next iteration of the `while()` loop you overwrite the file stream pointer with `stdout`, effectively leaking an open file. You should instead make sure to close the file before beginning the next iteration of the loop. Like below:

```
while(1)
{

    outfile = stdout;
    infile = stdin;

    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    printf("%s$ ",cwd); //prompt with cwd

    fgets(in, sizeof(in), stdin);

    char * fileref;
    if((fileref = strstr(in,">")))
    {

        fileref = strtok(++fileref, DELIM);
        outfile = fopen(fileref, "w");

    }

    token = strtok(in, DELIM);
    if (token != NULL)
    {
        if(!strncmp(token, EXIT, sizeof(EXIT)))
        {

            token = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
            if (token == NULL)
            {
                printf("Exiting with status code 0.\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            else if (isdigit(*token))
            {
                int code = *token - '0';
                printf("Exiting with status code %d\n",code);
                exit(code);
            }
        }
        else if(!strncmp(token, PWD, sizeof(PWD)))
        {
            fprintf(outfile, "%s\n",cwd); //This should get written to the file if I provide a redirection
        }
        else
        {
            fputs("\n", outfile);
        }
    }
    if(fileref)
    {
        fclose(outfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had reworked my shell using open and dup2 but I'll try this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

^C is sending the KILL signal to your program (KILL). You should use ^D to end the input instead (EOF).

> ```
>    fgets() returns s on success, and NULL on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read.
> ```

So you have to use: `while (fgets(in, sizeof(in), stdin)) {}`

Comment: He is writing his own custom shell. These conventions may not apply as it is at his discretion whether he follows them or not.